# Windows Form 1 Google Search button that opens second Windows Form and loads Page

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

So here is my setup so you can better understand what I am trying to do.  I have the following:
Windows Form 1 (Toolbox) with a textbox for the Google Search and a Search Click button that loads the secondary Windows Form (Search Engine).  I am wanting to do the following.

- Type the search criteria in my text box and clicking on the Search button which will open the secondary Windows Form (Search Engine) which will load the google search on the (Search Engine) form using "WebBrowser1"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  If you can provide code instead of where to go that would be best :)

Updated Code:  Which opens the Google Search Engine but does not display on the Webbrowser1.  Any additional assistance would be appreciated

**Form 1 Search button click Code:**

```
namespace Plumchoice_Toolbox
{
  public partial class plumchoice_Form1 : Form
  {
    public plumchoice_Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void plumchoice_Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Search Engine Form 1 added

    //// Search Button that opens the Search Engine
    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Google_Search.SearchEngineForm1 frm2 = new      Google_Search.SearchEngineForm1();
        frm2.searchAddress = "http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=" + textBox3.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
        frm2.Show();
    }
```

**Webbrowser1 Code**

```
namespace Google_Search
{
  public partial class SearchEngineForm1 : Form
  {
    public SearchEngineForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string searchAddress;
    private void PlumChoiceToolboxForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(searchAddress);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: In form1 search button click

This code is for **Form1** that has a search text box and a button for start searching. I think (but not sure) it is same as your **Toolbox** form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//When user clicks on search button
    {
        SearchEngineForm1 frm2 = new SearchEngineForm1();
        frm2.searchAddress = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + txtSearch.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

And below is the **Form2** or **SearchEngineForm1** that will open after search button click.

```
public partial class SearchEngineForm1 : Form
{
    public SearchEngineForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string searchAddress;
    private void SearchEngineForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Url= new Uri(searchAddress);
    }
}
```

In your code you have a mistake:

```
private void PlumChoiceToolboxForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(searchAddress);
}
```

What is this void? This will never fire. You need to double click on **SearchEngineForm1** form (a blank space on form) to add this void to your code:

```
private void SearchEngineForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Do not forget double click i said. Pasting this only does not help you!**

then enter the `webBrowser1.Url= new Uri(searchAddress);` between its braces {} to have this exactly:

```
private void SearchEngineForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Url= new Uri(searchAddress);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply Farzin, can you reply back with the scenario using Form 1 class called "Toolbox" and Form 2 class called "SearchEngineForm1"  So I can get a better understanding?  Thank you again!

Comment: I got the code added and it loads Form2 SearchEngineForm1 but no page loads in the browser1 item.

Comment: Form1 code:
 private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Google_Search.SearchEngineForm1 frm2 = new Google_Search.SearchEngineForm1();
frm2.searchAddress = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + textBox3.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
frm2.Show();
}

Comment: Code Form 2 SearchEngineForm1

namespace Google_Search
{
    public partial class SearchEngineForm1 : Form
    {
        public SearchEngineForm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string searchAddress;
        private void PlumChoiceToolboxForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(searchAddress);
        }

Comment: Sorry for my late. Is your form1 that has the search text box, named "Toolbox" ?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it is more clear to you.

Comment: So the main form is called toolbox_Form1 and the actual second form is called SearchEngineForm1.  The first code is giving me the following issue:
SearchEngineForm1 frm2 = new SearchEngineForm1(); is giving an error but it is taking Google_Search.SearchEngineForm1

Comment: So I am taking it requires the namespace combined with name?

Comment: Do the `SearchEngineForm1` and `toolbox_Form1` have different name spaces? It is better you edit question and put your code, Then it would be easy to solve the problem. And when you are about an error, It is very important to mention **What is the error** Because there will be many errors.

Comment: Code added for you to check.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  The current code opens the second form but does not display the Google Search results.

Comment: I show you the problem at the end of my answer. Please have a look.